# PHP unit 9: Test Dependencies does not work for me

Tags: php, phpunit

The following **PHPUnit** code has taken from their own website and it does not work for me, even though the documentation says it is working.

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class MultipleDependenciesTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testProducerFirst(): string
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
        return 'first';
    }
    
    public function testProducerSecond(): string
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
        return 'second';
    }
    
    /**
     * @depends testProducerFirst
     * @depends testProducerSecond
     */
    public function testConsumer(string $a, string $b): void
    {
        $this->assertSame('first', $a);
        $this->assertSame('second', $b);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> 1. MultipleDependencyTest::testConsumer
>    ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function MultipleDependencyTest::testConsumer(), 0 passed and exactly 2 expected`

Comment: Tested right now with **PHPUnit v9.5.4** and **PHP 7.3.24**, it works. Can you give us the PHPUnit version you installed ? Search in the **composer.lock** or with `composer show` (and if you only want to display the version: `composer show phpunit/phpunit | grep versions`).

Comment: As @AymDev asked, what PHP version and PHPUnit versions are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading/downgrading PHPUnit and PHP versions will do the trick. Try the setup as suggested by @AymDev in the comments.